# Flutter - sending base64Encode string to web-api problem

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass base64Encode string to my web API. I could encode image and pass base64Encode string to my api but i got "**Request-URI Too Long**"  message from API.
how can i solve this problem ?

```
static Future<AskModel> addArticle(String title, String content, String base64Image) async {
    var url = Uri.http(Config().baseUrl, Config().baseUrlPathAddArticles, {
      'title': title,
      'content': content,
      'base64Image': base64Image,
    });
    var response = await http.post(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return askModelFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your using a POST method, so you can set your `title`,`content` and `base64Image` in the body instead of in the url : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data#2-sending-data-to-server